# How to isolate a tag along with its content

Tags: html, tags

I took an **HTML** code from the **list of followers** of an IG and Need to isolate only the tag `title=" "` composed of its content, of course, and then remove this and leave only what is inside it, which in this case would be the names of users of the list and then need to put anteposed to the names the symbol @ ; so I took this HTML that I had pasted in Notepad++, and then I applied the HTML style, and it changed the color of the tags and suchs, but as it has many functions there, I do not know how to isolate only this tag, along with its content, so I was wondering if this is possible. The purpose of this is to "extract" a Follower List manually.

**I'll show you in stages what I'd like to do.**

**Part 1:**

```html
src="imagelink.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fjed4-3.fna.fbcdn.net&amp;_nc_ohc=FvRIGkb-0bMAX_sPaHj&amp;oh=d9f9a628561f79f8ec6eee273de1c9de&amp;oe=5F9A258F&amp;ig_cache_key=*******"></a></div></div><div class="enpQJ"><div class="d7ByH"><span class="Jv7Aj mArmR MqpiF  "><a class="FPmhX notranslate  _0imsa " title="USERNAME" href="/username/" tabindex="0">Username</a></span></div><div class="wFPL8 ">Username</div></div></div><div class="Pkbci"><button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " type="button">Follow</button></div></div></li><li class="wo9IH"><div class="uu6c_"><div class="t2ksc"><div class="Jv7Aj mArmR   pZp3x"><div class="RR-M-  SAvC5" aria-disabled="true" role="button" tabindex="-1"><canvas class="CfWVH" height="40" width="40" style="position: absolute; top: -5px; left: -5px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"></canvas><a class="_2dbep qNELH kIKUG" href="/noplaceliketr/" tabindex="0" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;"><img alt="Profile pic of noplaceliketr" class="_6q-tv" data-testid="user-avatar" draggable="false"
```

**Part 2:**

```
title="USERNAME"
```

**Part 3:**

```
USERNAME only.
```

**Final Part:**

```
@USERNAME
```

**PS:** I don't have much experience with programming, I know just the basics.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question and provide the code you have tried and explain what problem you are facing with that code.

Comment: @Omkar76 Ok, done!

Comment: which language are you using to parse this? javascript? Java? C#?

Comment: @Josste Java, i think. :)

Comment: if you read [ask]  (which is a guide to help you write an answerable question) it says to provide an [mcve]. it looks to me like you have an idea and haven't tried anything yet. If you haven't decided on a language, how can we help you actually fix your issue? let's say someone posts an answer using C# and you cannot use it. the question is answered, but you are not helped. please [edit] your question and help us answer it for you ;-)

Comment: furthermore, if you just want to do it in motepad++ with the search function that's not really a programming issue.